# Running Linux gpioget on pin connected to logic HIGH voltage always reads zero

Tags: linux, gpio

Working with the QSXP-M181 SOM from Ka-ro Electronics we have a line tied to GPIO bank 2 pin 18 which is physical pin 41 on the device (pin 50 to the Linux kernel).  It has been verified with a multi-meter that this pin is correctly attached to logic HIGH voltage.  The `gpioinfo` dump for that bank is as follows :

```
gpiochip1 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   7:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   9:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  10:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  11:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  12:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  13:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  14:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  15:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  16:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  17:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  18:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  19:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  20:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  21:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  22:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  23:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  24:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  25:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  26:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  27:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  28:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  29:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  30:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  31:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
```

When doing `gpioget 1 18` (this is the correct reference for this pin) it always returns zero.  The contents of the gpio directory are:

```
ls /sys/class/gpio
export  gpiochip0  gpiochip128  gpiochip32  gpiochip64  gpiochip96  unexport
```

If the pin is first claimed with `echo 50 > /sys/class/gpio/export` and `echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio50/direction` we can see that this works, but reading `/gpio50/value` still returns zero.

```
ls /sys/class/gpio
export  gpio50  gpiochip0  gpiochip128  gpiochip32  gpiochip64  gpiochip96  unexport
```

It is not clear what is being done incorrectly here.  Operations using `gpioset` on the system pins that are outputs produce the correct results.  Apparently `chardev` is supposed to be the replacements for these methods, but it does not run from the command line.  What else can be investigated to see why these input pins always read zero?

EDIT #1 : Response to "Have you configured the pin control correctly in Device Tree?" (I tried to make this a comment, why is there a character limit when you need to reply to people?)

I am working from this reference : https://developer.technexion.com/docs/using-gpio-from-a-linux-shell which says nothing about the device tree, so I cannot confirm anything about that without additional details as to how to verify the device tree settings or correct them if they are wrong.  I should also mention that the aforementioned site says that if products use gpio expanders you have to check the `base` file to correctly derive the kernel pin number, if I do `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip32/base` I get 32, which fits with the generic ((bank - 1) * 32) + pin formula I was using, which also works to correctly turn on the LEDs on the pins we have attached to outputs.  I should also mention that the `gpioinfo` indicates that all gpios seem to default to input anyway.

Comment: Have you configured the pin control correctly in Device Tree?

Comment: @0andriy, see EDIT #1